# Rails Devise skip_forgery_protection not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, csrf

I am trying to skip forgery protection in a pin confirmation controller but the skip forgery protection method does not seem to have an effect. The verify_authenticity_token function is always ran.

FYI skip_forgery_protection looks like:

```
def skip_forgery_protection(options = {})
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, options
end
```

My controller looks like:

```
class PinConfirmation < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  
  skip_forgery_protection only: :confirm_pin

  def pin
    # render pin confirmation page
  end

  def confirm_pin
    # do pin confirmation 
  end

end
```

For some reason verify_authenticity_token is ran despite the fact that skip_forgery_protection is defined above.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation I found that after manually removing the CSRF token from the form and submitting with `skip_forgery_protection` both on and then off, the forgery protection is actually skipped even though the `verify_authenticity_token` is being ran in both cases. The skipping seems to happen at the lower level than this function.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in `Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController` and it isn't working.

Comment: @Coderama my initial thoughts was that `skip_forgery_protection` was not working and that forgery protection was still being ran for my skipped action. I based this on the fact that the debugger was stopping inside the `verify_authenticity_token` function. However when testing by removing the CSRF token from my form I found that regardless, the forgery protection was not running for the action I skipped. So it was working as expected and I interpreted things wrongly.